# ThreadSanitizer with GCC 4.9.0 - TSAN_OPTIONS ignored

Tags: gcc

I am using ThreadSanitizer with GCC 4.9.0 running under Ubuntu 2.04.

TSAN Compile switches are 
-fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIE

TSAN Link switches 
-fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pie

I am running the program from within GDB 7.4.

ThreadSanitizer itself is working properly, but it is ignoring the TSAN_OPTIONS environment variable.

I set the environment variable from the command line before running GDB as follows:

export TSAN_OPTIONS=report_bugs=0

I have confirmed that TSAN_OPTIONS is set as expected, both from "printenv" on the command line and also from within the "C" program under test, using getenv().

For example the above setting, which should stop bugs from being reported by ThreadSanitizer, fails to stop bugs being reported by ThreadSanitizer.

Some other switches I have tested are suppressions and log_path.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I have noticed that TSAN_OPTIONS is written as  TSAN_OPTIONS=report_bugs=0 ./a.out with an addition "./a.out" at the end. An explanation on this is appreciated. There is really no place where the TSAN_OPTIONS syntax is fully explained. Also as an additional clue I am seeing the same issue of options being ignored recognizing with ASAN_OPTIONS.

Comment: The additional parameter is likely the name of the process for which the options will be applied. I have tried adding this, but the result is the same: options specified by TSAN_OPTIONS are ignored by ThreadSanitizer.